# Qt static deployment on windows

Tags: qt, qt4

I try to deploy static and I configure like many guides on the internet:

1. Go to qt folder
2. Edit \mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf:
   QMAKE_LFLAGS = -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc
   to (add -static -static-libgcc)
   QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static -static-libgcc -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc
3. configure -static -release -no-exceptions

And I have this error when I release my app :

- :: error: cannot find -lQtGui ::
- error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit
  status

I did try to find on the internet but unfortunately I've found nothing . How can I fix this ?

Comment: How does your qmake .pro file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Qt SDK? If I recall correctly, the SDK doesn't come with the static libraries by default and you're going to need to compile it.

And, by the way, you can add linker flags by adding them in your .pro file instead of editing the default Qt files.

Answer (score 0):

This error is from C++ linker. For some reason you have no path to you QtGui library.
Do you have in you qmake file following line?

```
CONFIG += gui
```